# dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement doesn't work

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I want to kill session over dblink however dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement doesn't work.

Below command doesn't throw any error but also it doesn't kill the session.

```
exec dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@dblink('Alter system kill session ''274,12303,@1'' immediate');
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to kill session which resides in a remote database. If that's so,

- create a procedure in that (remote) database
- it would kill session

  - one option is to use dynamic SQL to do that (i.e. `execute immediate`)
- which one? The one whose parameters will be passed as procedure's arguments
- call the procedure over the database link

Comment: I knew the alternative ways to do it. The problem is making in this way. It supposed to work but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the session with sid=274, serial=12303 on node=1 is running a heavy DML/DDL statement, and that by saying "it doesn't kill session" you mean that the session is seen as ACTIVE in GV$SESSION after the command is run.

That is an expected behavior. As counter-intuitive as it may be, KILL SESSION doesn't really "kill" session - it sends a kill signal which the session will respect after it's current work is done. Not before. So not an option for the assumed scenario.

Two other options:

- `ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION '274,12303,@1' IMMEDIATE`
- kill OS process.

[ORACLE-BASE article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions#kill_session)

P.S. `dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@dblink(q'!Alter system kill session '274,12303,@1' immediate!');` [alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617). No more double-ticks since 10g.

Comment: nope, it is just dummy session which are created it on sqlplus. still doesn't kill. and also tried with q'! but it also didn't work.